# Android disable right-edge UI in immersive mode?

Tags: android, android-layout

By default in a landscape Android app in Immersive mode, you can show the system UI by swiping from the right edge or the top edge. Is there any way to prevent a right-edge swipe from opening the system UI, so that the system UI can only be opened from the top edge of the screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot do this as a security measure. The user should always have a consistent way to reintroduce the status bar, as well as navigation bar on devices with on screen keys. Allowing third party developers to disrupt this would be a terrible idea.

Comment: I would argue that swiping from the top should always show the system UI, but swiping from the right should be optional. I suddenly realize why Google hasn't brought the old Android browser's Quick Controls over to Chrome. I guess we're stuck with outdated touch mechanics for the next few years.

Comment: As I mentioned, on devices with on screen keys, the right edge is where the navigation bar sits. So it makes sense to respond to a swipe on this edge if you want to get to the home/back/recents button. Having to swipe from the top then move to the right hand side to press the button would be illogical and disruptive.

Comment: I understand where the navigation bar sits and the benefit of allowing swipe from the right side to open the navigation bar. The problem is that it's crippling to advanced touch interfaces. Did you ever try the Quick Controls in the old browser? I suppose that this is the price we pay for sacrificing hardware buttons to reduce fragmentation.

Comment: I don't use my devices in landscape very often so never had an issue. At any rate, if I've answered your question (even though you were hoping for a better answer), please vote and accept it :).

Comment: For future reference, when someone asks an innocent question, calling the question a "terrible idea", "illogical", and "disruptive", can come across as antagonistic and rude :)

Comment: Fair point, but I was just trying to explain the reasoning behind not allowing it, not questioning your desire to do so.